# Is there any way to get SharePoint Site Creator Email and Site Status using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, graph-api-explorer

I would like to get the email of the site creator (Site Created by) using MS Graph API, also the current status of the site (Active, Deleted etc..).

Could you please help me with the query.

I searched in MS article but I couldn't get the proper query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Creator and status of SharePoint site are not available in Microsoft Graph.

You can see that there is no suspicious information in the [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of the site.

You need to get the required information using PowerShell or CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no creator and stauts property in the site resource according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0

So you cannot achieve this via graph api. I would suggest you use rest api instead.